# Doubt about substitution in $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{2+\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

While evaluating
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{2+\cos x}$$
I thought about letting $t=\tan \frac{x}{2}$, but I get the obviously wrong result
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{2+\cos x}=\int_0^{\tan\pi} g(t)dt=\int_0^0 g(t)dt=0$$
Which is not possible, since $\frac{1}{3} \leq \frac{1}{2+\cos x}\leq 1$ hence
$$\frac{2}{3} \pi \leq \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{2+\cos x} \leq 2\pi$$
Why is this wrong? Is this related to the fact that $\tan \frac{x}{2}$ is not one-to-one in $[0,2\pi]$? If the problem is that, couldn't we just consider $(0,2\pi)$? The integral should be the same in the open interval, am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: $$\tan\dfrac x2$$ is not even continuous at $$x=\pi$$

Comment: Do the integral on $(0,\pi)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

As commented $$\tan\dfrac x2$$ is not even continuous at $$x=\pi$$

To avoid discontinuity, use if $f(2a-x)=f(x),$

$$\int_0^{2a}f(x)=\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_a^{2a}f(x)dx$$

Set $2a-x=y$ in the second integral.

Here $a=\pi$

Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I don't completely get the situation: $\tan \frac{x}{2}$ is not even defined for $x=\pi$, so how can we talk about continuity in a point where $f$ doesn't even exist?
I get that I can do the integral by splitting it or using the formula you've written, but I would like to know what is the mistake in my approach (for example knowing what I'm violating in integration theory or what hypothesis I'm missing in theorems). Thanks!

Comment: @ZaWarudo : The function value in a single point is not relevant to the value of an integral over an interval of this function where the single point occurs. Unless you include distributions in your class of functions.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $t=\tan\frac x2$ is undefined at $x=\pi$, which does not implies an antiderivative valid across $x=\pi$ and hence invalids $\int_0^0 g(t)dt=0$. Instead, integrate as follows

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{2+\cos x}= 2\int_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{2+\cos x}=4 \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{3+t^2}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}
$$